# Incrementing a variable by watch command

Tags: bash, watch-command

I want a variable to be incremented by 1 per second.

```
#!/bin/bash
var=0
watch -n 1 echo "$((var++))"
```

**Output** (after few seconds) :

```
Every 1.0s: echo 0
0
```

It didn't change on screen but when i enter `echo "$var"` output is 1.Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really easy to do this with `watch`, but possible. I'll explain it below.

However, if you only want a counter that increments once per second, and don't really have to use `watch` for any other reason, you can simply solve this with a shell loop and a `sleep`:

```bsh
var=0
while sleep 1 ; do echo "$((var++))" ; done
```

If it is not possible to convert your `watch` command into a loop like this, or of course if you are interested in why it doesn't work the way you tried to do it, read on.

---

For one, your first problem here is that in

```bsh
watch -n 1 echo "$((var++))"
```

Bash will first expand your arithmetic expression and then run the command, so it actually runs

```bsh
watch -n 1 echo 0
```

and then increments `var` once, which is why you get `1` as value afterwards.

---

Now you could put it in single quotes instead of double quotes, but then no expansion is going to happen at all and it will output `$((var++))` literally all the time. We can put it through `eval` though to evaluate the string again. This evaluation will then happen every second.

Because `watch` uses `sh` by default, we need to use a different arithmetic syntax, as it doesn't support `++`: `$(( var += 1))` - Note that this will increment the variable first and then return the incremented value, unlike `$((var++))` which first returned the original value and then incremented the variable.

```bsh
watch -n 1 eval 'echo $((var += 1))'
```

This will unfortunately print `1` inside the watch, and the final value of `var` will stay `0`.

Why? The watched command runs in a subshell. Subshells have their own, isolated environments and variables.

---

You can export your variable of a parent shell (the one where you type) to its subshells (those inside which the watched commands run) by running `export var` once before the `watch`, but that only gives them read-access. Every change to the variable, like the increment, is still only happening inside the subshell and not propagated to the parent.

If you `export var` as described, the watched output will constantly be whatever starting value you have set + 1, but the final value of the variable will remain the starting value.

---

So, we learned that there is really no way to directly pass a variable from a subshell to its parent, so whatever happens inside the watched command can neither affect the variables and environment of your parent shell, nor can the changes persist across calls of the same command by `watch`.

We need some kind of temporary storage that is not bound to the shell environment where we can read and write our current counter variable. For example, a file:

```bsh
export temp=$(tempfile)
echo 0 > "$temp"
```

This creates a temp file with random name in `/tmp`, remembers its name in the exported shell variable `$temp` and writes your starting value 0 to it.

Now inside your watch, you have to read your variable from that file, then you can increment it and do whatever you want, but in the end you must write your changed value back to the file:

```bsh
watch -n 1 'read var < "$temp" ; echo "$((var+=1))" ; echo "$var" > "$temp"'
```

This will finally make your watch count up. However, don't forget that you have to read the last value from the file into your parent shell variable again, if you still want to access it after your watch is over, and also don't forget to delete the temp file again:

```bsh
read var < "$temp"
rm "$temp"
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Here's a slight alternative which also clears the screen each run to create an effect more like `watch`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64406172/4561887